# Yarn / IIS URL rewrite

Tags: reactjs, iis, url-rewriting, asp.net-web-api2, hadoop-yarn

I have a React app deployed to production as a `bundle.js` and `index.html` pair, served up by IIS under a url like:

`https://my-app.com`

This talks to a .Net WebAPI backend, served up by IIS as a virtual application at

`https://my-app.com/api`

This allows the React app to make requests to the relative url `/api/XXX` and successfully hit the API.

My problem is when developing with these 2 projects running locally.

The API is run in Visual Studio 2015 in debug mode and IIS Express makes it available at `http://localhost:56585/api/` (easily configurable).

While developing the React app I use JS development tools such as `yarn`, which provides a webserver hosting the app at `http://localhost:3000`.

The different webservers and different ports precludes the use of a relative url to contact the API when running locally.  This means I have to hardcode the url my api hits, and change it before I build based on the target environment.  Eg:

```
//const base_url = '/api/'; // production
const base_url = 'http://localhost:56585/api/'; // development
```

Is there any way to configure some kind of rewrite rule such that requests my client makes to `/api/XXX` get remapped to `http://localhost:56585/XXX`, *without* rewriting requests to the root url (eg `http://localhost:3000/index.html`)?